# How can I change order of calculation in stack algorithm?

Tags: python

Hi I'm trying to make postfix increment operator by using simple stack algorithm. If I input
20 4 /, I need to get result of 5. But in my code, the last input comes first so the result becomes 0.2. How can I make it while maintaining my form??

```
class stackcl:
   def __init__(self):
       self.items = []
   def push(self, item):
       self.items.append(item)
   def pop(self):
       return self.items.pop()

arr = stackcl()
str = input().split()
x = 0

for c in str:
   x = 0
   elif c == '/':
       x = arr.pop() / arr.pop()
   elif c >= '0' and c <= '9':
       x = 10 * c + c
       c = int(c)
   arr.push(c)

x = arr.pop()
print(x)
```

Comment: The code shown has syntax errors. Please show your actual code. Furthermore, Looks like you're trying to implement Reverse Polish Notation. Your class is really pointless as it's just a wrapper around a list. Think about re-writing the class to handle the calculation to make it worthwhile - i.e., a true OO approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stacks works as LIFO (Last In, First Out). So, when you push something to stack, you push it to the top of the stack. When you pop something from the stack, you get the element at the top of the stack (last pushed element).

I think the first element of "str" is 20. But there is no suitable case in if statements for 20. So it is pushed to stack.

Now stack is : 20

Then 4 comes, and it is pushed onto stack.

Now stack is : (Bottom) 20 -> 4 (Top).

Then "/" comes and below line works.

```
elif c == '/':
       x = arr.pop() / arr.pop()
```

First pop function pops 4 from stack because it is on the top. Then second pop function pops 20 from stack. 4 / 20 = 0.2 :)

**EDIT**

To make it work, maybe you can try this;

```
elif c == '/':
    lastElement = arr.pop() // which is 4
    firstElement = arr.pop() // which is 20
    x = firstElement / lastElement  // 20 / 4 = 5
```